# android .apk size increased

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, eclipse-adt

I noticed that the application size of my app, as reported by android, was doubled respect to the same application two months ago, despite I did only minor modifications.
Even building the .apk from the same source code I used two months ago, I obtain a bigger .apk.
I did some investigations and noticed that the classes.dex was way bigger. It seems that something changed in the build environment. Is it possible that the last android SDK causes bigger .dex classes? is it due to something else?
I'm using android SKD inside Eclipse Indigigo:
Android SDK Tools rev. 21
Android SKD Platform-tools rev. 16

Comment: Interesting.. you know that you can get previous sdks and try that? It takes lots of time.. But in any case double size sounds like a lot. Did you check the resources, u sure they did not change?

Comment: Did you also try to clean up your project?

Comment: shot in the dark... possibly your smaller build was obfuscated, but you forgot to obfuscate your larger build?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned up the project many times. I reinstalled a tagged version from scratch too, so I'm quite sure the very same sources give a quite different classes.dex file

Comment: @ab11: unfortunately not, neither was obfuscate

Comment: Try 'Analyze APK' with both old and new builds.

Answer (score 1):

Check your resources, Check whether you included or excluded some libraries from the project, Check your .jar files in the project.Clean and build your project.